# Fancybox - reload page or load new page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a login link that opens a [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) and asks the user for their username/password.

I send the user input to a PHP script to validate, which returns an error message on error, or redirects to the home page on success.

- When an error message is received, I want the error message to reload in the same parent Fancybox.
- On success, I want the Fancybox to close and load up the home page in the primary window.

Another issue is that my css isn't loading on `#fancyboxLogin`, but it loads fine on `$fancybox`.

HTML:

```
<a class="fancyboxLogin fancybox.iframe" href="/login">Log In</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancyboxLogin").fancybox({
        type: "iframe",
        afterClose: function () {
            parent.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In the html page replace

```
<a class="fancyboxLogin fancybox.iframe" href="/login">Log In</a>
```

with this line

```
<a class="fancyboxLogin fancybox.ajax" href="/login">Log In</a>
```

for the error message you can simply validate using a javascript function with ajax and show the message in a div tag.

And if the the validation is success then simply submit the form using javascript submit() function which submit the login form and refresh the page.

and for the javascript fancybox script simply put:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancyboxLogin").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 700,
        maxHeight   : 500,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
   });
```

I hope this can be of some help

Comment: Thank you for answer. However, what I am trying to do is the following: I am using php to validate the form (in the cases where javascript is disabled), and since php does not have ajax capabilities, I need to reload the fancybox with the error message.